# Error Hilt Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is 1.0

Tags: kotlin

Please someone how to fix this error?

> > Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
> > Values of variant API AnnotationProcessorOptions.arguments are queried and may return non final values, this is unsupported
> > error: [Hilt]
> > Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
> > at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:206)
> > at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:187)
> > at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
> > at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:56)
> > at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isVisibilityInternal(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:148)
> > at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.PkgPrivateMetadata.of(PkgPrivateMetadata.java:94)
> > [Hilt]
>
> ```
>       at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.generateAggregatedDeps(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:355)
>       at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processModule(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:283)
>       at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processEach(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:121)
>       at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:194)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
>       at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:985)
>       at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:901)
>       at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1227)
>       at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1340)
>       at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:310)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:256)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
> at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
>
> ```
>   [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
>    > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
>
> * Try:
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.3'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
        hilt_version = '2.47'
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    //id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}


android {
    namespace 'com.wladimirbr.readerbook'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wladimirbr.readerbook"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

def hilt_version = '2.38.1'
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2"


    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0' // para work manager
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"


    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

    // OkHttp
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2")

    // JSON Converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10'
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/77045693/16177121